# Disabled Lazy loading still loads related entity. Why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have disabled Lazy Loading but entity is automatically loaded from the database when property referring to the entity/entities is accessed. Why? It should not be accessible any more?

```
My EF version="6.1.3"
```

The following line loads department data whereas i am expecting it should not because i have disabled Lazy Loading and also navigation property is non-virtual.

```
Student student  = context.Student.select(x => x.Department).First();
```

**Classes:**

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Age { get; set;}
    public string Date { get; set;}

    public Department department { get; set }
}

public class Department
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public class Name { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set }
}
```

**Context**

```
public StudentContext : DbContext
{
    public StudentContext()
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    }

}
```

Comment: Your query is explicitly asking for the Department.  Of course it's going to load the Department data.

Comment: So you want [Lazy Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)? You have everything configured for eager loading (no virtual, accessing the child, turning it off).

Comment: thanks, so my understanding of Lazy loading was wrong. You mean, even though lazy loading disabled but if we access navigation property using x.blah, EF would explicitly load it and will not complain that "Lazy Loading is disabled so i can't load it. Better you try Eager Loading or Explicit Loading,"

Comment: If you explicitly query for X, it will give you X.  Lazy loading / eager loading applies to *child entities*.  You're loading a `Department`.  That department's `Student` object should be null, because you didn't request it explicitly and lazy-loading is disabled.

Comment: What's the point of disabling of lazy loading than? Still we can load navigation by x.blah even though it is disabled... Also even if lazy loading enabled context.Student.First() will not load Department until i do x. Department. Enabling/Disabling lazy-load does make any difference?

Comment: You can get to the Department because you're explicitly asking for it **in the query**.  Lazy-loading comes into play with the `Student` property on that department, because it *wasn't part of the original query*.  EF isn't going to avoid returning data you explicitly ask for.

Comment: Making sense. probably last point if:- 'LazyLoadingEnabled = true' Then why context.Students.First() does not auto load Department property in Student? off course Department is marked as virtual navigation in student. still i have either Include or explicitly load Department.

Comment: If lazy loading is enabled and you reference the Student's `Department` property, it should load that property if it contains data.  If you want it to load the Department *with the original query*, you need to `Include(...)` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong idea of what "lazy loading" means.

```
context.Student.Select(x => x.Department).First();
```

You are explicitly requesting a `Department`.  EF is going to honor that request.  There is nothing 'lazy' about your query: you are *explicitly* asking for a `Department`.

Yes, you are requesting a `Department` through a navigation property, but this doesn't matter because you aren't working with an instance of a `Student`.  **You are directly issuing a query to the database**.

You now have a `Department`.  Lazy-loading now comes into play because you are done making *explicit* queries.

That department has a child property, `Student`.  Because lazy-loading is disabled, this property will be null even if the data exists in the database.  If you reference the property, it will be null, because lazy loading is disabled - EF won't automatically fetch the data for you.  You must **explicitly** query for that property.

Okay, so say you explicitly request a `Student` object.  It's `Department` property will be null because lazy-loading is disabled.  Referencing that property won't cause it to be loaded.  You will have to explicitly query for that property.

Comment: Thanks, I got it clearly.

Answer (score 5):

What is lazy loading?

> It's ability to load related data by doing separate database query *after* you have
>   executed some initial SQL query and loaded some entities.

First of all let's review your classes:

- Deparment is not 1:1 relation with students. Each department can contain lot of students
- Student don't have an ID property
- Department should probably have integer ID
- In order to support lazy-loading navigation properties should be *virtual*

With these in mind you'll get following classes:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's look what happens **when lazy-loading is enabled**. E.g. you are loading student:

```
Student bob  = context.Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Bob");
```

That will generate query similar to

```
SELECT TOP(1) Name, Age, Date, Department_Id 
FROM Students
WHERE Name = 'Bob' --actually name will be passed as query parameter
```

And what is more important, that SQL query will be executed and response from server will be loaded into memory and mapped to `Student` entity. Nothing related to department except its ID was loaded. Now if you'll try to get department details

```
 var departmentName = bob.Department?.Name;
```

EF will generate SQL query for loading related department details. Something like

```
 SELECT d.Id, d.Name 
 FROM Students s
 INNER JOIN Departments d ON s.Department_Id = d.Id
 WHERE s.Id = 42 -- assume Bob has this id
```

And this query will be executed. That's a second roundtrip to server. That's how lazy-loading works.

When **lazy-loading is disabled** there will be no second query to server. You will have only data which you loaded with first query. I.e. department entity will be `null` and you will not be able to get it's name.

---

And now your case - you are loading department data by first query. Actually your code will not compile, because you should use `Department` entity:

```
Department dep = context.Student.Select(x => x.Department).First();
```

Enabling or disabling lazy-loading will not affect that. Because as I just wrote, lazy-loading affects further queries which load related data. But not first the query which loads initial data. In your case it will look like

```
SELECT TOP(1) d.Id, d.Name
FROM Students s
LEFT OUTER JOIN Departments d ON s.Department_Id = d.Id
```

Comment: Thanks, excellent explanation.

Comment: @immirza you are welcome. Just remember - lazy-loading gives you benefits of easy access to related entities like if they are already loaded from server, but you should be careful because each time you are doing new roundtrip to database